# MediaWiki modifying properties sets them to "protected" forever

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

After modifying a property in SemanticMediaWiki, the property is set to "protected" during change propagation. But this protection should go away after all changes have been propagated. Unfortunately in my case a property is still marked as "protected" though clearly all jobs seem to have been processed.

Is this a bug or a feature? Does anyone know about this? How can I make the system recover from this situation?

Comment: Did you try to run job queue?

Comment: Of course. The result: No change.  That's the reason why I write this question: I have no idea how to resolve this situation now :-/

Comment: Is anyone reading this and has an idea how to resolve the situation?